# How can I select one(or zero) entry from multiple tables, and add these values together to match a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, algorithm

I'll make it clearer here. Now suppose I have 3 tables, and contents of them are like follows:

```
table 1:
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
2    0    1    3    0    0    2
0    2    -1   0    0    1    0
4    0    0    2    1    0    0
0    0    3    0    2    0    5


table 2:
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
-1   2    3    3    0    4    0
3    0    0    2    0    0    1
1    0    1    -2   1    3    0
0    2    -3   0    3    0    0


table 3:
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
0    4    5    -1   0    2    0
0    -2   3    0    0    0    -4
3    0    0    -4   1    3    0
1    0    -1   5    2    0    6
```

And now I need to select **zero to one** entry from each table, where the sum of one or more certain attributes(A-G) equals certain values I specifies.

For example:

My requirement is

> sum of A = 8

So i can select

```
1st row from table 1, 
2nd row from table 2,
3rd row from table 3.
```

Or requirement:

> sum of G = 8

then I select

```
1st row from table 1,
4th row from table 3.
```

Or requirement is

> sum of C = 7 and sum of A = 8

I can have

```
2nd row from table 1,
1st row from table 2,
1st row from table 3.
```

This is a simplified version of my case. In my database, attributes(A-G in tables above) can be as many as 150, and selected attributes can vary from 1 to 6, and target values of each attribute are usually 10, 15 and 20. Though total amount of attributes in one entry is big, only 1 to 4 attributes have non-zero values. Also, I have 5 such tables.

Of course the way of selecting entries that satisfy the requirement can have many versions. For example, when I give the requirement:

> "sum of C = 7"

I can select

```
4th row from table 1,
3rd row from table 2,
2nd row from table 3;
```

while I can also take

```
1st row from table 1,
1st row from table 2,
2nd row from table 3;
```

So can I implement this feature by some advanced sql query techniques?

Comment: in short. With this data. you don't need three tables. All three tables contain similar data. combine them into one. If you have a real problem post that instead of this.

Comment: show output as table for us easy to answer

Comment: I think you are not  handling your requirement correctly from the beggining.What is your real requirement like ?

Comment: Also,what input you will pass,what output are you expecting ?

Comment: define what is you need in details ?? ... if the input will be 7 why the output should be 4th row from table 1,
3rd row from table 2,
2nd row from table 3;

Comment: also determine what is your database, is it SQL Server , or MySQL . Delete one of them from tags.

Comment: @e4c5 Yeah although the tables contain similar data, I still need 0 or 1 from each table, and if I combine all of them how do I tell which is from which table?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Hi I think I defined what I need. If the input will be 7 the output should be 4th row from table 1, 3rd row from table 2, 2nd row from table 3; because C values in these three rows add up to 7. I think mysql is enough.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Which part of the requirement is not clear to you? I'll refine them. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, please post your real problem istead of this a,b ,c nonsense

Comment: @Gardevoir Cannot get what is meaning of "add up to 7" .... let focus into 7 as input - you said the output should be 4th row from table 1, 3rd row from table 2, 2nd row from table 3 ??? ... why ? what is the relation between input and output  ?? sum of first output result is 10 , second is 4 , third is -3 ... the total of them is (10 + 4 + -3) = 11 , where is 7 ?? -

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Really sorry for that. By writing "selecting rows" I mean selecting C values from these 3 rows from 3 different tables. In 4th row of table 1, attributes C have value 3, and in 3rd row of table 2, attributes C have value 1, and in 2nd row of table 3, attributes C have value 3. So the sum of the values of attribute C is 7.

Answer (score 0):

See in first place, I was telling that you have not cover your requirement properly .no problem,in another thread you can share your real problem that lead you to this solution.There are several reason to think about it.

Secondly,I had to use cursor for now,the more I am confident abou your requirement ,better the query will be written.

First,you try my script with various sample data and tell me which output is wrong.

```
declare @table1 table(A int,B int,C int,D int,E int,F int,G int)
insert into @table1 values      
(2, 0,1  , 3 , 0,0, 2)
,(0, 2,-1 , 0 , 0,1, 0)
,(4, 0,0  , 2 , 1,0, 0)
,(0, 0,3  , 0 , 2,0, 5)

declare @table2 table(A int,B int,C int,D int,E int,F int,G int)
insert into @table2 values  
(-1,   2,   3 ,   3 ,  0 ,   4,    0)
,(3 ,   0,   0 ,   2 ,  0 ,   0,    1)
,(1 ,   0,   1 ,   -2,  1 ,   3,    0)
,(0 ,   2,   -3,   0 ,  3 ,   0,    0)

declare @table3 table(A int,B int,C int,D int,E int,F int,G int)
insert into @table3 values  
(0,4  ,  5  ,  -1 ,  0 ,   2 ,   0)
,(0,-2 ,  3  ,  0  ,  0 ,   0 ,  -4)
,(3,0  ,  0  ,  -4 ,  1 ,   3 ,   0)
,(1,0  ,  -1 ,  5  ,  2 ,   0 ,   6)

DECLARE @ColNum int=3
declare @ReqSum int=7
DECLARE @Table1Number INT=0,@Table2Number int=0,@Table3Number int=0
DECLARE @i int=0,@j int=0,@k int=0
declare @t table(Table1Row int,Table2Row int,Table3Row int)
Declare @Exit bit=0

DECLARE @getTable1Number  CURSOR
SET @getTable1Number = CURSOR FOR

SELECT case when @ColNum=1 then A 
            when @ColNum=2 then B
            when @ColNum=3 then C
            when @ColNum=4 then D
            when @ColNum=5 then E
            when @ColNum=6 then F
            when @ColNum=7 then G
end
FROM @table1
OPEN @getTable1Number
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable1Number INTO @Table1Number
WHILE(@i<(Select count(*) from @table1)) 
BEGIN
set @i=@i+1
print 'i :'+cast(@i as varchar)
Set @j=0
set @k=0
set @Table2Number=0
 set @Table3Number=0
if(@Table1Number+@Table2Number+@Table3Number=@ReqSum)
Begin
insert into @t (Table1Row ,Table2Row ,Table3Row )VALUES(@i,@j,@k)

        set @Exit=1
    BREAK;
End
if(@Exit=1)
BREAK;
----------Declare @Table2 cursor here
DECLARE @getTable2Number  CURSOR
SET @getTable2Number = CURSOR FOR
SELECT case when @ColNum=1 then A 
            when @ColNum=2 then B
            when @ColNum=3 then C
            when @ColNum=4 then D
            when @ColNum=5 then E
            when @ColNum=6 then F
            when @ColNum=7 then G
END
FROM @table2
OPEN @getTable2Number
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable2Number INTO @Table2Number
WHILE (@j<(Select count(*) from @table2)) 
BEGIN

set @j=@j+1

set @k=0
print 'j :'+cast(@j as varchar)
set @Table3Number=0
if(@Table1Number+@Table2Number+@Table3Number=@ReqSum)
Begin
insert into @t (Table1Row ,Table2Row ,Table3Row )VALUES(@i,@j,@k)

        set @Exit=1
    BREAK;
End

if(@Exit=1)
BREAK;
----------Declare @Table3 cursor here
DECLARE @getTable3Number  CURSOR
SET @getTable3Number = CURSOR FOR
SELECT case when @ColNum=1 then A 
            when @ColNum=2 then B
            when @ColNum=3 then C
            when @ColNum=4 then D
            when @ColNum=5 then E
            when @ColNum=6 then F
            when @ColNum=7 then G
END
FROM @table3
OPEN @getTable3Number
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable3Number INTO @Table3Number
WHILE (@k<(Select count(*) from @table3)) 
BEGIN
set @k=@k+1
print 'k :'+cast(@k as varchar)
if(@Table1Number+@Table2Number+@Table3Number=@ReqSum)
Begin
insert into @t (Table1Row ,Table2Row ,Table3Row )VALUES(@i,@j,@k)

        set @Exit=1
    BREAK;
End

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable3Number INTO @Table3Number
END
CLOSE @getTable3Number
DEALLOCATE @getTable3Number
------ End @Table3 cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable2Number INTO @Table2Number
END

CLOSE @getTable2Number
DEALLOCATE @getTable2Number
------ End @Table2 cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getTable1Number INTO @Table1Number
END

CLOSE @getTable1Number
DEALLOCATE @getTable1Number

select * from @t
```

Here understand this,
DECLARE @ColNum int=3 -- you have to pass ordinal number of column for which you want sum.(1=A,2=B,3=C etc)
declare @ReqSum int=7 
so for example sum ofA=8 that means pass @ColNum=1 and @ReqSum=8

Output table is :declare @t table(Table1Row int,Table2Row int,Table3Row int)
which return for above input as suppose

```
Table1Row   Table2Row   Table3Row
1                 2       3 

       Which means 1 rows from table1
                   2nd rows from table2
                   3rd rows from table3
```